# End(xlToRight) sends me to the last colum--XFD i want to go to the next column, not the last column

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA I am comparing two columns.  If the the value in column H appears in column B I want to past a value in the next blank cell to right of column H.

```
For Each ThisCell1 In Range("H5:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
    'This is the range of cells to check
        For Each ThisCell2 In Range("B5:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        'This is the range of cells to compare
    If ThisCell1.Value = ThisCell2.Value Then
            ThisCell1.End(xlToRight).Value = Range("B4")
```

My code puts B4 in column XFD, but I want it in column I, J or K.  What am I doing wrong.

Comment: if the next cell is blank `End(xlToRight)` will go to either the next cell that has a value or the last column depending on which comes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the next cell is blank `End(xlToRight)` will go to either the next cell that has a value or the last column depending on which comes first.

come in from the last column instead:

```
cells(thiscell1.row,columns.count).End(xltoLeft).offset(,1) = Range("B4")
```

This will find the last occupied cell in that row and move over one.

One more note:

Get in the practice of assigning the parent sheet to **All** Range Objects

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet.
    .cells(thiscell1.row,.columns.count).End(xltoLeft).offset(,1) = .Range("B4")
End with
```

Comment: We have a winner.  Thank you for your prompt attention.

Comment: @Michael1964 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It will remove this from the unanswered queue.